# Apply Attribute 'Scrolling=yes' to All iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, tumblr

Currently working with a Tumblr theme. The theme has it set so that you can't scroll vertically, you can only scroll horizontally. The way this is set is by setting `<iframe scrolling="no">`. When I change it to `scrolling=yes`, it allows a vertical scroll. Unfortunately, the code for the `iframes` does not show up in the HTML editor for Tumblr. I can only change it in the Chrome JavaScript Editor.

Is there a way to change all `iframe` tags to include `scrolling=yes` directly from the HTML editor?

Note: the HTML editor also accepts CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are OK with jquery solution then try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('iframe').each(function(){  
   $(this).attr('scrolling','yes');
   });
 })
```